# How to create unnamed network namespaces in linux like docker?

Tags: namespaces

I found "ip netns" can't list the netns created by docker. After some searching, I still can't find out how to create such unnamed netns. What is the API to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unshare command. After typing "unshare -n bash", you are in an unnamed netns now.